# HTML5 Video Autoplay In Slider Issue

Tags: jquery, video, html, slider, autoplay

I've integrated the JW HTML5 player into my jQuery Cycle slider. The problem is if I set the video to autoplay it plays when the page loads and not when that slide comes into view - which is what happens with Flash videos. Is there a way to prevent HTML5 videos from playing until their slide is shown?

This is the code I'm using:

```
 <video id="video-'.$video_name.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" poster="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/lib/scripts/timthumb.php?src='.$image.'&h='.$height.'&w='.$width.'&zc=1" controls="controls">
    <source src="'.$html5_1.'" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="'.$html5_1.'" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="'.$html5_2.'" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

<script>
    jwplayer("video-'.$video_name.'").setup({
        file: "'.$url.'",   
        image: "'.get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/lib/scripts/timthumb.php?src='.$image.'&h='.$height.'&w='.$width.'&zc=1",
        icons: "'.$icons.'",
        autostart: "'.$autostart.'",
        stretching: "'.$stretching.'",
        controlbar: "'.$controlbar.'",
        skin: "'.$skin.'",
        screencolor: "white",
        height: '.$height.',
        width: '.$width.',
        players: [';                    
        if($fallback == "flash") {
            $out .= '{type: "html5"}, {type: "flash", src: "'.get_bloginfo("template_directory").'/lib/scripts/mediaplayer/player.swf"}';
        } elseif($fallback == "html5") {
            $out .= '{type: "flash", src: "'.get_bloginfo("template_directory").'/lib/scripts/mediaplayer/player.swf"}, { type: "html5" },';
        }
        $out .= ']
    });
</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

set `video` tag `Attribute` `preload="auto"`

preload attribute Specifies if and how the author thinks the video should be loaded when the page loads. default value of `preload` is `none` you can set it to the `metadata` or `auto`

Answer (score 0):

See this opera dev article:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/

You can tie the play() function into your js to start the video when that slide loads.

Comment: Thannks Grillz. The problem is I'm not sure how to tie that function to the slider.

Comment: I would need to see your js, but I would tie logic into the next/prev buttons with something like: if slideshow div ID == video div id then play()